# About short videos

Tags: animation, licensing

So, I want to make a short animation on my Youtube. Can it be monetised? Which licenses do I need to avoid legal problems?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

See this page:
[“Any creation you make as an artist with Blender is your sole property, and can be applied for any purpose you choose to.”](https://www.blender.org/support/faq/#using-blender-1)

Also see this:
[“The official Blender logo is a registered property of Blender Foundation.
“](https://www.blender.org/about/logo/)